# Why did this fish kill my Kissing Gouramis?

Tags: aquarium, fish, identification

I got two of these recently, and they killed my Kissing Gouramis. The shop owner said that they would be compatible.  I don't know what kind of fish it is, nor what would have caused them to kill my Kissing Gouramis

[image: Fish in question]

Comment: identifying breeds are a little of topic here but what you have got is a shubunkin type of goldfish https://www.caringpets.org/how-to-take-care-of-a-goldfish/types/ .

Comment: Not sure how to address this, but that shop owner gives bad advice. Goldfish are cold water fish, Kissing Gouramis are tropical. Their temperatures don't match. And as goldfish are herbivores, they are unlikely to have killed your Kissing Gouramis, unless you have seen them attack and eat them, that is.

Comment: @Flummox They actually attacked them non stop. I have a heater on standby. What temperature do you recommend for these Goldfish?

Comment: We may have another discussion on identification on meta.

Comment: all of the information you will need is here http://thegoldfishtank.com/ and if you do a search for goldfish here on this site you will find more information.

Comment: I have raised Koi for years ( more or less goldfish) and I never saw one attack anything but vegetables and floating food  .

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on how they were kept, as to what happened to your gourami. They are tropical, as prior commented while these shubunkin goldfish are cooler water fish, as also commented :) Most goldies prefer 72-75F for their waters, so many lower state residents don't have to use heaters that often unless they get into colder climate seasons. These guys are also considered pond fish and need quite a bit of room to grow-growing to the size of their tank is a bit of a myth, wherein their body will become stunted and their organs will continue to grow till they cannot handle that anymore. They are fun, funky little fish that are lots of fun. You can check out Solid Gold Aquatics on youtube, Jenny has some outstanding videos on their care and needs.

Sometimes, fish will start picking at the slime layer of other fish and this can lead to sickness and/or death. It's not completely unusual for goldfish to become curious or nibble at another fish, but it often varies per the species and even then.. they all have their own personalities lol.